# How can I create a container from the jboss amq-7-broker-image repo image

Tags: docker, jboss, amq

I'm new to Docker and these topics in general. I should create a container from [this image](https://github.com/jboss-container-images/jboss-amq-7-broker-image?tab=readme-ov-file), but not so absolutely where to start. I've seen tutorials, articles, etc., but I'm certainly missing some steps. Could anyone tell me how I can do it? This is the repo where the image should be or at least the content on how to create it.

I have tried them all but unfortunately to no avail. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Red Hat AMQ 7 is based on ActiveMQ Artemis. I recommend you use an [official ActiveMQ Artemis image from Apache](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/activemq-artemis/tags) rather than creating your own. However, if you really want to create your own you can follow [these instructions](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/docker.html#build-your-own-image).

Comment: It's worth noting that the repo you linked hasn't been updated in 7 years so you should definitely use something newer.